KivyMD MDButton - ImportError
It looks like kivyMD doesn't want to be learned by me. Or maybe I'm not learning in the right way. After solving an installation problem, now I have one with kivyMD. Even if I try a simple code like the one in https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/button/ (I'll copy the code below) I have this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "c:\Kivy.md\Myquizlet\intento.py", line 2, in <module>
     from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonIcon, MDButtonText
 ImportError: cannot import name 'MDButton' from 'kivymd.uix.button' (C:\Kivy.md\virt\Lib\site-packages\kivymd\uix\button\__init__.py). Did you mean: 'button'?

The code is as following:
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import MDButton, MDButtonIcon, MDButtonText
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen


class Example(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Green"
        return (
            MDScreen(
                MDButton(
                    MDButtonIcon(
                        icon="plus",
                    ),
                    MDButtonText(
                        text="Elevated",
                    ),
                    style="elevated",
                    pos_hint={"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5},
                ),
                md_bg_color=self.theme_cls.surfaceColor,
            )
        )


Example().run()

I'm using kivyMD 2.0.0. Any ideas?
I've tried to use an MDButton in other codes, but it's still not working. If you need, I'll post the other codes, but it's basically the same.

Actually - it looks like there are problems with using version 2.0.0: https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/issues/1609
Sounds like you already ran into this possibly? Check the issues in the GitHub repo for this package and ask for help there if you don't find a helpful answer here

Thank you! I'll check tomorrow. Hopefully it's that.

Seems no problem to me when i run the codes. Just make sure you install the KivyMD 2.0 version using this: pip install https://github.com/kivymd/KivyMD/archive/master.zip

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Thanks! I did that and solved the problem. Now I'm having another with Tabs, but I'm focused on something else, so I'll let it pass for now.
